What is a ball in cylindrical coordinates?
I'm struggling to understand what a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is in cylindrical coordinates. Let $\Phi:(0,\infty)\times [0,2\pi]\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the transformation $(\rho,\varphi,z)\mapsto (\rho \cos(\varphi),\rho \sin(\varphi),z)=(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$. The ball with center $0$ and radius $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is described as
$\begin{align}
B(0,1)=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1\}.
\end{align}$
By the transformation it is
$$\begin{align}
B(0,1)=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq 1\}.
\end{align}=\{(\rho,\varphi,z)\in (0,\infty)\times [0,2\pi]\times \mathbb{R}: \sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}\leq 1\}.$$
Since this set doesn't depend on $\varphi$ geometrically we can think of it as rotating the set $\begin{align}
\{(\rho,z)\in (0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}: \sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}\leq 1\}
\end{align}$ around the vertical axis. The latter set is a half ball in $(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and by rotating it one gets the ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Question:
I thought that sets in cylindrical coordinates correspond to cylinders. So in order to get a cylinder we need a rectangle in the the plane of the variables $(\rho,z)$. But the $\begin{align}
\{(\rho,z)\in (0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}: \sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}\leq 1\}
\end{align}$ is a half ball in the plane and not a rectangle. This really irritates me. Is my idea of cylindrical coordinates wrong or is there something I don't see? I would be grateful for any thoughts on this topic!

Your post needs some proofreading. You have mixed up $\zeta$ with $z$ in some places. You have mixed up $\rho$ with $r$ in other places.

@LeeMosher thanks, now it should be fine. I just fixed $r=1$.

Horizontal cross-sections of balls are disks with varying radii. So if you wanted to describe the volume of a sphere this way, you'd effectively be breaking it up in thin cylinders whose radius is largest at the equator and very small near the top/bottom. (This is not how you'd think of surface area in cylindrical coordinates---compare with the staircase paradox in 2D.)
